# Python-Sphinx: select only a given superclass from multiple inheritance documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-sphinx

My current situation is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

class A(object):
    def print5(self):
        """prints 5"""
        print(5)

class B(A, pd.DataFrame):
    def print6(self):
        """prints 6"""
        print(6)
```

So I want to document **B** with all its functions with *sphinx*'s autodoc, which would look like:

```
.. autoclass:: B
:members:
:inherited-members:
```

The issue is that I want the functions documented in **A** to appear, but not all the **DataFrame** documentation. Is there a way to document only from a particular parent class but not all?

Thanks!

Comment: What I can think of is to remove `:inherited-members:` and enumerate all the members you are interested in: `:members: print5, print6`.

Comment: Yes, my current two solutions where that one or go the other way around and add the `:exclude-members:` and list all the `DataFrame` functions (this has the advantage that it would update as I add new functions to either the class or the superclass). Still, I hoped I was missing some more obvious and automatic solution...